# Copying a folder in a windows explorer

Tags: c++, windows, testing

Im just wondering if anyone can tell me how does windows deal with copying a folder in windows explorer? So if i right click on a folder and then copy it and move somewhere else and paste it.

Im just wondering because im writing tests for a file system driver, Basically allowing the hardware im working on to be explored through windows explorer like any other hooked up piece of hardware. So i need to test and confirm that it can copy folders. Copying Files has a Copyfile function. But does anyone know how i go about testing copying a folder. I was gonna do the following: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/125446, but i dont know if that is how windows does it so i dont know if it will be enough. Same for Moving a folder.

Any help is appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood the shell uses [`SHFileOperation` or `IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Vista+.